# Is it possible to have the objects I draw not have the image I set as the background?

Tags: javascript, css, webgl

I have this program where my canvas assumes a WebGL context and I'm trying to upload an image as the background, but when I do so, everything becomes the image itself:

[image]

I achieved this by fiddling with my css files and setting the `background-image:` to what I wanted. But I would really like if only the background itself would be the image, and not the objects I draw.

Any tips?

This is my shader.frag code:

```
precision highp float;

const int MAX_LIGHTS = 8;

struct LightInfo {
    bool active;
    bool directional;
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 ia;
    vec3 id;
    vec3 is;
};

struct MaterialInfo {
    vec3 ka;
    vec3 kd;
    vec3 ks;
    float shininess;
};

varying vec3 fNormal;
varying vec3 posC;

uniform int uNLights; // Effective number of lights used

uniform LightInfo uLight[MAX_LIGHTS]; // The array of lights present in the scene
uniform MaterialInfo uMaterial;  // The material of the object being drawn

uniform mat4 mView;
uniform mat4 mViewNormals;

void main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LIGHTS; i++) {
        if(i == uNLights) break; 

        if(uLight[i].active) {
            
            vec3 L;
            if(uLight[i].directional) {
                L = normalize((mViewNormals * vec4(uLight[i].pos, 0.0)).xyz);
            } else {
                L = normalize((mView * vec4(uLight[i].pos, 1.0)).xyz - posC);
            }

            vec3 V = normalize(-posC);
            vec3 N = normalize(fNormal);
            vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);

            float diffuseFactor = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);
            float specularFactor = pow(max(dot(R, V), 0.0), uMaterial.shininess);

            vec3 ambientColor = uLight[i].ia * uMaterial.ka;

            vec3 diffuseColor = uLight[i].id * uMaterial.kd;
            vec3 diffuse = diffuseFactor * diffuseColor;

            vec3 specularColor = uLight[i].is * uMaterial.ks;
            vec3 specular = specularFactor * specularColor;

            if(dot(L, N) < 0.0) {
                specular = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            }
            
            gl_FragColor.xyz += vec3(ambientColor + diffuse + specular);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood "*everything becomes the image itself*", what is "the image"? is it the draw or the `background`? Btw, `background` **will always be overlapped by the content**, whether it is text in a div or a draw in a canvas.

Comment: You should try using the ```z-index```

Comment: I’m not clear what this means. Please provide a simple code example.

Comment: To me it looks like you're multiplying not only RGB but also A with your lighting equation, hence the objects become transparent and are blended with the background. Show your shader code.

Comment: @Leo the image is a png. I didn't want the sphere and ground to be that png too. It's hard for me to explain

Comment: @Brightumor I just started learning webgl and js, I'm not that well versed in it yet, could you elaborate?

Comment: @LJᛃ updated my question with the code, it's an implementation of the Phong lighting method.

Comment: You should initialize `gl_FragColor` to something like `vec4(0,0,0,1)` before operating on it. What's your clear color?

Comment: @LJᛃ With the image as it shows, none, I don't do clearColor. With clearColor(0,0,0,1) everything turns black except the Sphere and Ground, which "gain" the image

Comment: Note that those are two different things, clearing the buffer to 0,0,0,1 fills it with black and an alpha of one, initializing `gl_FragColor` to that value in your shader will ensure that everything that is shaded will have an alpha of 1 which is what you want.

Comment: @LJᛃ that makes sense, and seemed to work. Now I have one more problem. Is it possible have the background all black when I have no lights in the scene? I currently store them in an array lights, so maybe a check someone for when lights.lenght == 0, I just don't know what to check for. Is it possible to alternate between a background color and a background image?